# In SQL*Plus, how do I run @https://here.is.url/script.sql behind a proxy?

Tags: windows, sqlplus, scripting

In SQL*Plus, I try to run a script that is stored at a certain URL.

From where I am currently, I can http(s) connect with the internet only via a proxy.

So, if in SQL*Plus, I try

```
@https://here.is.url/script.sql
```

SQL*Plus won't find the script (as SQL*Plus doesn't seem to know about the proxy).

Is there a way to indicate what proxy to use and how to authenticate with that proxy?

Comment: The usual way (at least for Unix) to set a proxy is to set the environment variable HTTP_PROXY. So try setting HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyhost - I imagine it'll work the same for windows

Comment: Stupid comment system... You need http:// after the equals sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`.

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyhost
```